# Issue with menu items and content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I do not have any issues with code so I do not write code here.

So my problem is the following:
  I have a menu.
  When I click on a menu item I want to display some content;
and when I click on an other menu item I want to display some other content/
I do not know how to achieve that.
(I want to make I kind of one page website)
 Someone can help me?

Comment: If you want to make one page website, you can navigate the menu using id attribute of the element.

Comment: As you've tagged jquery: https://api.jquery.com/click http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ https://api.jquery.com/html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_events.asp

The above links should help.  These are DOM events.   You need to set up a function that changes the content you want by using innerHTML or textContent.  Then set up a click event on the link/button/etc.. that you want to click to cause that change.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <body>
      <h1 id="changeMe">I am some text.</h1>
      <button onclick="changeText()">Click Me!</button>

  <script>
    function changeText() { 
    document.getElementById("changeMe").innerHTML = "I am the changed text!";
    }
      </script>

    </body>
      </html>
```